# Recoil Tutorial findIndex

Tags: javascript, recoiljs

In the Recoil tutorial at https://recoiljs.org/docs/basic-tutorial/atoms, they use
`const index = todoList.findIndex((listItem) => listItem === item);`
to get the index of an object in an array. The code works but I can't replicate it, I always get a return value of -1. I thought you couldn't compare objects directly like that?
The `todoList` is something like:

```
[{id: 0, text: 'item1', isComplete: false}, {id: 1, text: 'item2', isComplete: false}]
```

where `item` is `{id: 0, text: 'item1', isComplete: false}`

Comment: You would probably be able to get more help with this if your question was clearer.

Answer (score 0):

They are used logic like this:

```
const a = {};
const b = [];
b.push(a);
b.findIndex(el=>el===a); // 0
```

if you defined list by your own:

```
[{id: 0, text: 'item1', isComplete: false}, {id: 1, text: 'item2', isComplete: false}]
```

you should use `id || text || isComplete` to find index, because you don't have a link to the object that you want to find.
More about object comparision https://dmitripavlutin.com/how-to-compare-objects-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You're imagining that the `===` is comparing the object by *value*, when in fact it is comparing them by *reference*, see below.

```js
const todoList = [];

const item = {id: 0, text: 'item1', isComplete: false};
todoList.push(item);

// Attempt by reference, 0
console.log(todoList.findIndex((listItem) => listItem === item));

// Attempt by value, -1
console.log(todoList.findIndex((listItem) => listItem === {id: 0, text: 'item1', isComplete: false}));
```